# Rpi 4B + 3.5 inch display

Tags: pi-4, display

I have acquired a 3.5 inch 480x320 display with a XPT2046 touch controller to use with Raspberry Pi 4B
Right now my Rpi runs an Ubuntu server, and I was wondering if it is possible to use this display to see ubuntu server terminal, without needing the SSH.

The display looks exactly as the one from this lcdwiki page: http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display

The Ansible method from https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257076/how-get-lcd-3-5-touch-screen-working-on-pi-4b-ubuntu-20-04-server didn't work

I would appreciate any ubuntu server-oriented guides if you have any

Thank you!